# The re.subn doesn't subsitute the results

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am trying to substituted some content from text, and remove it. Using subn I want to both substitute and keep track of what wa substituted.

My entire code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re

regex = re.compile(r'\<begin_block\>(.*?)\</end_block\>', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

test_str = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mi eros, eu euismod urna congue a. <begin_block> Some content here </end_block>Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada congue nec eget ipsum. \n"
            "<begin_block>\n"
            "Hello world!\n"
            "</end_block>\n"
            "Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est. \n"
            "<begin_block>\n"
            "##########\n"
            "</end_block>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print("Match {matchNum} was found: {match}".format(matchNum=matchNum,
                                                       match=match.group()))
    string, num = re.subn(regex, r'\n', test_str)
```

**Can someone explain what I am doing wrong, I fail to see this?**

**EDIT: After comments,**

For example, if I search for "`<begin_block>`", this still finds all 3 of the tags, despite that I ran subn on them. This is why I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT 2: After more comments,**

I tried this, modified the last lines to this:

```
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    string, num = re.subn(match.group(), r'\n', test_str)

print(string)
```

**My results, the content is not substituted properly:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mi eros, eu euismod urna congue a. <begin_block> Some content here </end_block>Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada congue nec eget ipsum.
<begin_block>
Hello world!
</end_block>
Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra
aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est.
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Please describe the behavior you're seeing, and what you expect instead.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Perhaps I'm dumb but it still seems unclear to me.  Maybe show us the actual vs expected results?

Comment: Edited again sorry!

Comment: @JohnSmith You're aware that `re.subn` does not modify the string inplace? I.e. if you check it again after all the substitutions it's still going to be the same.

Comment: @a_guest he did assign `string, num = re.subn(regex, r'\n', test_str)` so I'm assuming that's not the issue.  The regex matches as well.  Unless he's checking `test_str` instead of `string`.

Comment: @Idlehands Yes but substitution is performed on `test_str`. Sure, even if checking `string` it would only reflect the last substitution and not the ones before.

Comment: @a_guest, I know, that's why I am asking for, how I can achieve this, while still using subn and then doing one substitution at a time or so. I want to be able to track substitutions precisely.

Comment: Are you checking `string` or `test_str`? because `string` returns the subbed string just fine.

Comment: The idea is to modify the test_str and also to keep track of how many substitutions were successful using current pattern, and what returned 0, and where not successful. Maybe this gives an idea, also while string modifying the original string, the test_str.

Comment: Then you should be assigning `test_str, num =  re.subn(...)`.  But then again, the first `re.subn()` would already replace all matches.  You just want it replaced one at a time? Then `test_str, num = re.subn(regex, r'\n', test_str, count=1)`.  But then I fail to see the point of `num`.

Comment: @Idlehands, regardless, what would be more efficient?, if subn substitutes, all, then that's good, but how does it allow me to precisely know what parts where substituted.

Comment: `num` tells you how many substitution is completed.  See the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn.  If doing it in one go is sufficient, you don't even need to iterate through `matches`.

Comment: @Idlehands, I know, I read it from the documentation when I started using it.

Comment: In which case, perhaps it's a better approach to describe what exactly you're trying to achieve, because I'm lost.  Based on my understanding of your needs (which is to substitute the string and see how many subs were done) my suggestions should cover the grounds plenty, but it doesn't seem like it's what you want...? Did you try my suggestions at least to see if the behaviour is what you wanted?

Comment: @Idlehands, can one use 'match.group()' e.g. substituting directly by value from the multiline string.

Comment: Then it's probably better you just use `str.replace()` instead of `re.subn()`.  I'll post an answer and see if it's what you want.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ok so my guess is you want to substitute something like: `r"abc(\d+)xyz"` but you also want to know what the `(\d+)` part was (for each of the substitutions). Is that correct?

Comment: @a_guest, what do you mean by (\d+), I know this is numeric. I honestly, what to know what pattern succeeded and what lines it manages to modify in the content string.

Comment: @JohnSmith For example `re.sub(r"abc(\d+)xyz", "abc?xyz", "abc123xyz abc456xyz")` then you want to obtain the string `"abc?xyz abc?xyz"` and *also* obtain the replaced values `"123"` and `"456"`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, try this instead:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\<begin_block\>(.*?)\</end_block\>', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

test_str = ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mi eros, eu euismod urna congue a. <begin_block> Some content here </end_block>Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada congue nec eget ipsum. \n"
            "<begin_block>\n"
            "Hello world!\n"
            "</end_block>\n"
            "Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est. \n"
            "<begin_block>\n"
            "##########\n"
            "</end_block>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print("Match {matchNum} was found: {match}".format(matchNum=matchNum,
                                                       match=match.group()))
    test_str = test_str.replace(match.group(), '\n', count=1)
```

`re.subn()` would replace everything in one go and return the number of substitutions occurred.  However if you are interested in substituting the items one at a time within your `matches` iteration, it's probably better to just use `str.replace()` since you don't need to recompile the `match.group()` string and consider the symbols within it.

You *could* use `re.subn(..., count=1) to achieve a similar result, but it is moot because`str.replace(..., count=1)` would achieve the same and you don't need to recompile the match string and in all likelihood perform better.

The results:

> ```
> Match 1 was found: <begin_block> Some content here </end_block>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mieros, eu euismod urna congue a. 
> Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada conguenec eget ipsum. 
> <begin_block>
> Hello world!
> </end_block>
> Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est. 
> <begin_block>
> ##########
> </end_block>
> Match 2 was found: <begin_block>
> Hello world!
> </end_block>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mi eros, eu euismod urna congue a. 
> Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada congue nec eget ipsum. 
>
>
> Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est. 
> <begin_block>
> ##########
> </end_block>
> Match 3 was found: <begin_block>
> ##########
> </end_block>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id lacus dapibus, sollicitudin nunc ut, posuere nisl. Fusce varius mi eros, eu euismod urna congue a. 
> Integer posuere tempor nulla eget commodo. Mauris iaculis vehicula nisi pretium interdum. Curabitur nec quam vel eros malesuada congue nec eget ipsum. 
>
>
> Vivamus aliquam lectus sapien, eget cursus libero congue sed. Mauris nulla metus, dictum ut semper non, sagittis non ipsum. Etiam fermentum pharetra aliquet. Morbi bibendum nulla quam, vitae vestibulum arcu bibendum a. Maecenas eget est vitae elit rhoncus scelerisque. Aliquam sagittis, ligula quis porttitor congue, ex nisi aliquam diam, ac ullamcorper quam lectus non est.
> ```

Comment: Sadly, I have tested exactly this approach. But, argue and convince me that this is more effective than re.subn or is there a better approach with this one? What do I mean: is 
**it possible to track precisely what was successfully replaced?**
**how it was replaced?**
**on what line in the original string it was replaced?**

Comment: You might want to use `str.replace(..., count=1)` in case there are multiple occurrences of the same substring.

Comment: Define "effective".  What is the purpose of your tracking of substitution to this precision? If you just wanted to know what was matched and is interested in the final result, `matches` will give you the former, and `re.subn` will give you the latter.  If you actually *need* the interim results however, this would be my approach because as my answer already states, you don't need to worry about recompiling against the matched string each time.  If you're talking about computing time, `str.replace()` would probably perform better over `re.subn()`, but I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: @JohnSmith if you needed that level of precision you will probably need to write your own function.  I'm not familiar enough with `re` module to point you to a function that is capable of telling you *where* and *which line* was replaced.  I'm assuming you're talking about something like a diff comparison.

Comment: Well, after further investigation, I think, I am going for `sub( ..., count=1)` since it probably allows me to precisely, figure out a way.  Thanks for all the input to everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure how `re.sub` would work because the `match.group()` string might not be matched again since it's no longer a raw string with the escaped symbols.  The benefit of `replace` over `re.sub` or `re.subn` is that you the exact string is matched instead of wildcards and escaped characters.  But hey, if it works on your implementation then all is well, it's a matter of preference.